# I can't wake up my HP laptop from sleep

Tags: laptop, windows-11, sleep, hp

I can't get my computer to wake up from sleep after it goes to sleep automatically (after a few minutes of inactivity). The power light indicates it's sleeping, but I can't wake it up with the mouse, keyboard, or power button. (I usually leave the lid open.) I have to restart the computer by holding down the power button.

**Update:** After installing the new Intel graphics driver (version 31.0.101.4824), my monitor connected with HDMI shows a blank screen with the mouse cursor. Before, the screen didn't show anything.

### Some things I've noticed

- I tried `powercfg /energy` ([report](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/r8ab5hqje1y7bur9ekhd0/energy-report.html?rlkey=iujs0cpqbqdcsol2e7u2g0kvp&dl=0)) but that didn't help.
- I tried `sfc /scannow`, but it couldn't find anything.
- I tried `dism /online /Cleanup-Image` with the `CheckHealth`, `ScanHealth`, and `RepairHealth` options. When I did `ScanHealth`, it said `The component store is repairable.` The other ones said `The operation completed successfully.`
- This has only been happening for a few weeks. I installed a bunch of updates for the Wi-Fi, Bluetooth, and other Intel stuff recently. (I don't know if that has anything to do with it.) Before the updates, if I let the computer sit idle, it would go to sleep, and eventually there would be a blue screen saying that it couldn't find the hard drive. Now, it's just a blank screen with the power light pulsing.
- There is no "Power" troubleshooter on my computer. I tried the AC adapter test in HP Support Assistant, but the program crashed before it could finish the test.
- There were no sleep-related problems with my computer when it had Windows 10.

### Specifications

- Model: HP Laptop 15t-dy200
- OS: Windows 11
- BIOS: F.32 (the July 2023 version)
- Graphics: Intel Xe Graphics, drier version 31.0.101.4084

Comment: As always, update UEFI before anything else.

Comment: Skip updating UEFI, considering it was working, try reinstalling the HP software. After that does not work there is a way to query to determine what is preventing your machine from going to sleep properly

Comment: Please post online your `powercfg /energy` report.

Comment: @ox15 - “I tried the AC adapter test in HP Support Assistant, but the program crashed before it could finish the test.” - That software….

Comment: Have you tried usual OS fixes, i.e., SFC & DISM?